# Eventos e alterações numa JSP?

Tags: javascript, jquery, java-ee, jsp, servlet

Olá.
Tenho um jsp sendo um chat(devido a uma restrição, estou usando o Struts 1). Neste JSP, tenho a seguinte `div`:

`<div class="conteudo" id="conteudo" name="conteudo">`.

Preciso, retornar uma resposta automática(pode ser qualquer coisa) do servidor sempre que o usuário enviar algo para a página de chat, o que não estou conseguindo fazer. Porém, tenho o script para exibir as mensagens do usuário na tela, e ele funciona.
O Script é o seguinte:

```
<script src="inc/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#enviar").click(function(){
                var mensagem = $("#texto").val();
                mensagem = mensagem.replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />');
                var cliente = "Cliente "+":";
                var hora = (new Date).getHours();
                var min = (new Date).getMinutes();
                if(min <10)
                    min = "0"+min;
                var sec = (new Date).getSeconds();
                if(sec <10)
                    sec = "0"+sec;
                var horario = hora+":"+min+":"+sec;

                $("#conteudo").append($("<div[...]{AQUI SE INSERE A MENSAGEM, E ELA FUNCIONA.}[...]</div>"));

            });
    });
</script>
```

Não há algo que eu possa fazer para dar uma espécie de `append` também?
Lembrando que preciso que uma mensagem qualquer seja inserida no chat após alguém digitar algo.

Answer (score 1):

Um jeito simples seria usar um polling AJAX. Alguma coisa mais ou menos assim:

```js
function alguemDigitandoAlgo(dados) {
  // ... Aqui é com você.
}

(function pollServerForNewMessage() {
  $.getJSON('/alguem_digitando_algo.jsp', function(response) {
    if (response.newMessage) {
      alguemDigitandoAlgo(response.message);
    }
    setTimeout(pollServerForNewMessage, 1000);
  });
}());
```

Outras alternativas superiores seriam usar comet ou websockets, mas o AJAX é a forma mais simples.

Além disso, você ainda tem que tratar os casos aonde a conexão falha, cai, etc.

Aqui a [fonte](http://reallifejs.com/brainchunks/repeated-events-timeout-or-interval/) de onde adaptei o código.